# LINQ Group by showing incorrect results

Tags: c#, linq

Linq group by is showing wrong mathematical results. I have tried to extract & minimize the code to the point.

```
public class ModelBO
{
     public string Code { get; set; }
     public double Amt { get; set; }
}


List<ModelBO> list = new List<ModelBO>();
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.97 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -3.36 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -0.01 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 1.42 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -0.01 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.03 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -0.14 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -0.02 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -0.05 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.03 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.06 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.01 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.51 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.29 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = -0.67 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.02 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.08 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.09 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.37 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.17 });
list.Add(new ModelBO { Code = "A2", Amt = 0.21 });

List<ModelBO> t = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Code }).Select(g => new ModelBO { Code = g.Key.Code, Amt = g.Sum(x => x.Amt) }).ToList();
```

Now, in results, t[0].Amt should be zero. But, I am getting different result. What must be wrong here.

Comment: Why do you group by `new { x.Code }` and not just `x.Code`?

Comment: In real example I am grouping by total 7 columns

Comment: If you got something like `2.2204460492503131E-16`, you may round a result. It happens due to internal representation of double and float numbers

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes, I get that result. I did try to round it off. Let me try again

Comment: @jay `Amt = Math.Round(g.Sum(x => x.Amt), 2)` should work fine

Comment: I see. Anyway, in binary it's only possible to accurately represent fractions formed of 1/2<sup>n</sup> (e.g. 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, etc.), so fraction combinations outside of that, combined with the limited precision of floating point values, means that you'll lose some information in situations like this. If you're dealing with money, you should use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: @John yes, I am dealing with invoice amount here. I will use decimal. Thanks for suggestion.